# User permissions in Keystone.js Admin UI

Tags: node.js, express, keystonejs

I am considering migrating an `express.js` app to `keystone.js` . The app serves an API (no pages) so we're interested in the admin ui and rich field capacities of Keystone.

We have a specific requirement I am trying to implement: we have users with documents. It is a many to many relationship. 
A user can have several documents and a document can be managed by several users. 
A user can only edit his/her documents.  I am able to show a user's documents in the UI but not to restrict the access to those documents. The canAccessKeystone field grants admin permissions on all content.

Can I achieve that and if yes, how?

Comment: Sorry to say that at the moment the KeystoneJS Admin UI does not have fine-grained user permissions.